Failed to schedule shutdown
I am attempting to utilize scheduled shutdowns on my DietPi but alas it does not appear to function.
Error Message:
$ sudo shutdown -P 60
Failed to set wall message, ignoring: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists
Failed to schedule shutdown: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.login1.service failed to load properly, please adjust/correct and reload service manager: File exists

Does anyone know how to solve this functionality? Thank you so much for any support you can provide.

From the messages it appears that you do not have root access to the shutdown command.  Could you post the sudo permissions for your ID.  Also not sure if this is also al problem but I've always put a + with the time  -P +60.
